# using strings inside if statement throw error "Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands string and string"

Tags: c#

Hi my c# is not what it used to be and have just come back after using java script for a while. 
Essentially I am just trying to do a simple if statement using index of arrays but I receive the error message.

```
"Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands string and string"
```

How come this is not allowed as it essentially becoming a bool.

```
            string[] userCustomAnswerArray = {"It needs to be reaplaced", "This could be improved", "I struggle to see this"};
            int customResponseindex = rand.Next(0, 3);

            string[] questionResponseArray = { "Yes", "No but not a problem", userCustomAnswerArray[customResponseindex]  };
            int questionResponseIndex = rand.Next(0, 3);
            string userAnswer = questionResponseArray[questionResponseIndex];

                    if (userAnswer = questionResponseArray[0] || userAnswer = questionResponseArray[1])
                    {

                    }
```

Thanks for your help !!!!

Comment: Equality operator is `==`, not `=`....

Comment: You forgot one `=` sign, do `userAnswer == questionResponseArray[0]` instead and your compile error will go away. I think your confusion comes from the fact that JS is dynamically typed while C# is statically typed. Plus, in C#, you cannot apply a logical operator (`||`) to any object (it needs to overload true and false as well as the `|` operator), only to a bool, where in JS you can (objects in JS are always truthy)

Comment: @MindSwipe You can apply the logical operator || to objects in c# - but only under specific circumstances - the type must overload the `true` and `false` operator as well as the `|` operator.

Comment: Using assignment operator  = ,use  == equality operator

Comment: @ZoharPeled thanks for pointing that out. I was able to edit my comment in time to include your info

Answer (score 1):

`userAnswer = questionResponseArray[0]` is incorrect.

`=` is the assignment operator while `==` is the equality operator